# Vagra up is not working for.ubuntu/jammy64

Tags: vagrant

$ vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

==> default: Box ubuntu/jammy64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...

default: Box Provider: virtualbox

default: Box Version: >= 0

==> default: Loading metadata for box 'ubuntu/jammy64' default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/jammy64

==> default: Adding box 'ubuntu/jammy64' (v20240126.0.0) for provider: virtualbox

default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/jammy64/versions/20240126.0.0/pro

Download redirected to host: cloud-images.ubuntu.com

default:

An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try again.

Failure writing output to destination

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.